# Filtering JSON request with JQ and bash scripting

Tags: bash, curl, jq

I'm requesting a JSON from Twitch with:
`curl --silent -H 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json' -X GET https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/$1` where `$1` is the input I send for my function.

Now what I'm aiming for is to filter the JSON by piping this after the curl: `| jq '.stream.channel.something'`
I am trying to get 3 different string values through jq filtering I can manage to get them to this level:

```
{
    "first": "lor"
    "second": "em"
    "third": "ipsum"
}
```

Way to operate with them inside the code?

---

Alternatives I've come up with are:

1. Create output of the curl, filter it and then delete.
2. Send 3 cURL requests -- (Useless performance hog?).

Comment: I'm not `jq`-enabled, so could you simplify your question? Are you saying that you have that curly-bracket-first-second-third string as output from `jq`? And you want to "operate" what with it?

Comment: Yes, after filtering it with jq, I'd like to use those three strings in my script to output them separately in my printf/echo command.

echo "First value: ${first}" etc.

Comment: Does jq have the ability to extract the "first" &etc values natively, or is that as far as jq goes? Thinking of saving the curl output to a temporary variable then calling jq to extract each.

Answer (score 2):

As I said, I don't know much about json or jq, but I wasn't able to get jq to parse your sample output of:

```
{
    "first": "lor"
    "second": "em"
    "third": "ipsum"
}

parse error: Expected separator between values at line 3, column 12
```

So I turned the input into:

```
{
  "stream" : {
    "channel" : {
      "something" : {
        "first": "lor",
        "second": "em",
        "third": "ipsum"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

... based on what I gathered from your call to jq. Hopefully that's similar to what the curl command is outputting.

If it is, then it seems like this sequence gets you what you want:

```
# this is just your original curl command, wrapped in command substitution,
# in order to assign it to a variable named 'output':
output=$(curl --silent -H 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json' -X GET https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/$1)

# these three lines take the output stream from above and pipe it to
# separate jq calls to extract the values; I added some pretty-printing whitespace
first=$( echo "$output" | jq '.["stream"]["channel"]["something"]["first"]' )
second=$(echo "$output" | jq '.["stream"]["channel"]["something"]["second"]')
third=$( echo "$output" | jq '.["stream"]["channel"]["something"]["third"]' )
```

With the results:

```
$ echo $first
"lor"
$ echo $second
"em"
$ echo $third
"ipsum"
```

Comment: apparently you can add the `-r` flag to `jq` to have it print the raw data (lor) instead of the JSON text ("lor"), if that's preferable.

Comment: Avoid .stream.channel.something.first format with jq, it's unreliable. it's better to use '.["stream"]["channel"]["something"]["first"]' It's guaranteed to work no matter if the keys include dots or hyphens and can save hours of pain. The OP example is missing comma separators.

Comment: I'll take your word for it, @css1971! I've updated answer with the new syntax -- no need for hours of pain!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your file is valid JSON (which the data in the question is not):

```json
{
  "first": "lor",
  "second": "em",
  "third": "ipsum"
}
```

You may use `jq` to create three assignments out of this, which you can evaluate safely in the shell:

```bsh
eval "$(
    jq -r '
        @sh "first=\(.first)",
        @sh "second=\(.second)",
        @sh "third=\(.third)"' file.json
)"
```

The `@sh` operator in `jq` will output assignments on the form `first='lor'` for the shell to evaluate.

For the `bash` shell, you could also create an array assignment:

```bsh
eval "$(
    jq -r '@sh "array=(\([.first, .second, .third]))"' file.json
)"
```

Here, the `jq` command would generate something like `array=('lor' 'em' 'ipsum')`, which when evaluated by `bash` would create the array called `array` with the given contents.

You could use the `jq` statement `@sh "array=(\([.[]]))"` to create an array of all keys' values, assuming each value is a scalar.